# Delete Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of records which are displayed in tabular format in a form. On each record there is a delete checkbox - here is the form in simplified format:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="update-history-form">
  Item 1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[0][delete]">
  Item 2 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[1][delete]">
  Item 3 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[2][delete]">

  <input type="submit" value="Update History" name="update">
</form>
```

The integer value in the input 'name' attribute helps identify which records have been selected for deletion.

What I want is for a JavaScript alert confirmation to appear if any of the delete checkboxes have been ticked (upon submit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#update-history-form').submit(function(){
  if ( $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length ){
    return confirm( "Really delete any of them?" );
  }
});
```

This will cancel the form submission of the user does not OK the confirmation dialog.

If you have non-delete checkboxes in your form you may need to modify the selector to only those inputs whose name [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) "delete", e.g.

```
$(this).find( 'input[name*="delete"]:checked' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#update-history-form').submit(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (this.find("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0 || confirm("Are you sure?")) this.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="" id="update-history-form" onsubmit='return confirmChecks(this);'>
  Item 1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[0][delete]">
  Item 2 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[1][delete]">
  Item 3 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="History[2][delete]">

  <input type="submit" value="Update History" name="update">
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function confirmChecks(someForm) {
  var inputList = someForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var aCheckboxIsChecked = false;
  for (var i=0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    if (inputList[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox' && inputList[i].checked) {
      aCheckboxIsChecked = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (aCheckboxIsChecked) {
    var proceed = confirm('Really delete those things?');
    if (!proceed) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```